# Disable or lock Google Play on my android phone

Tags: google-play-store

How can I disable/lock Google Play on my phone(may be restrict it with a password)? I tried [this way](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1626831) and followed the steps given there. But it's not asking any password for free apps.

Comment: You are running the support version of Google Play correct?

Comment: I didnt understand what is support version. When I go to settings in Google Play app, it shows me version as "3.10.10"

Comment: What do you mean *not asking any password for free apps* when you wanted to disable Google Play? Clarify?

Comment: If you want even more controle, you can have a look at some corporate apps. For example: [MobiControl](http://www.soti.net/Mobicontrol/AndroidPlus/) or [SureLock](http://www.42gears.com/surelock/surelockandroid.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't ask for a password for free apps since there's no danger of financial loss of any kind, it is a good point however

There are apps on Google Play that can 'lock' certain apps check 'https://play.google.com/store/search?q=app+locker' or something to that effect

This one looks like it does the job: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5kb21vYmlsZS5hcHBsb2NrIl0.

They will enable control of apps via a pin

Comment: There may not be any financial danger!!! But there can be adult apps(free) which kids are not supposed to download

Comment: I have just gone through the link, it locks the installed apps but what i want is stop Google Play from downloading anything

Comment: Oh.. I just got it. I think I can lock Google Play using this app. I will give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From google play download applockr or you can disable the app via settings>apps>all applications then by selecting the google play application and pressing the disable button to disable it until you want to enable it (do the same process but the disable button will be replaced with the enable button)

Answer (score -3):

I think the explanation on this post is what you need: http://www.android.gs/block-google-play-android-market-from-inappropriate-downloads/

Comment: Please don't use URL shorteners here.  As well, if the link goes down this answer is useless -- please summarize the relevant information in your answer.