# How can I lockdown an android phone?

Tags: security, permissions

I'm looking for a way to help lockdown an Android phone.  I want to be able to configure a phone so that only certain users can make calls/send messages to specific contacts.  It should also only allow access to specific applications, and disallow (un)installation of applications.

Is there any way to do this with Android?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about-other-android-related-questions) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) (or search Google Play for "app locker" :)

Comment: See also: [Double Security for Gmail](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43482/16575) / [Is there an application / ROM that allows me to set the phone to “Guest” mode which I can configure?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/31843/16575) / [Child-proofing an Android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25149/16575) / [How to mod android rom so none can ever install an app in it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39812/16575) / [Disable or lock Google Play on my android phone](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/37068/16575)

Comment: Seems to be a question about a problem rather than an app request. However it's almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: Perhaps, this has the answer: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25149/child-proofing-an-android-phone/25150#25150